# Android Tv RecyclerView focus Jumps

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-tv

I am developing android app for Android Tv. I have a RecyclerView in which there are items that can be iterated over using the remote control (D-pad). When I reach the end of the RecyclerView, the focus (the stroke around the item in the RecyclerView) jumps or flies off the RecyclerView. I want the focus to stop at the end. Thanks in advance

My fragment.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".TV.TvPopularFragment">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/progress_circle_style"/>


    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/moviesRecyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:nextFocusDown="@+id/moviesRecyclerView"
        android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>



</RelativeLayout>
```

My fragment.java

```
package org.vitaliy.moziapp.TV;

public class TvPopularFragment extends Fragment {


    FragmentTvPopularBinding binding;

    static public boolean isPopularOnTop = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = FragmentTvPopularBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        View root = binding.getRoot();


        RecyclerView moviesRecycerView = binding.moviesRecyclerView;
        ProgressBar progressBar = binding.progressBar;


        Display display = getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        display.getMetrics(outMetrics);
        float density  = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        float dpWidth  = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;
        int columns = Math.round(dpWidth/133);
        GridLayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(),columns);



        moviesRecycerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        PopularAdapter popularAdapter = new PopularAdapter(getActivity(),popular_posters,
                popular_title, popular_id, popular_categories, popular_votes_pos, popular_votes_neg,
                popular_last_episode);



        new CountDownTimer(10000, 1000) {

            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                if(AppActivity.isPopularCategoryLoaded) {

                    moviesRecycerView.setAdapter(popularAdapter);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    cancel();

                }

            }

            public void onFinish() {
            }
        }.start();




        moviesRecycerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
            @SuppressLint("NotifyDataSetChanged")
            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {

                int totalItemCount = mLayoutManager.getItemCount();
                int lastVisible = mLayoutManager.findLastVisibleItemPosition();

                boolean endHasBeenReached = lastVisible + 15 >= totalItemCount;

                isPopularOnTop = dy == 0;

                if (totalItemCount > 0 && endHasBeenReached) {


                    if(AppActivity.popularHasNextPage) {


                        AppActivity.popularPage += 1;
                        AppActivity.loadPopularCategory();


                        new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

                            public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

                                if(AppActivity.isPopularCategoryLoaded) {

                                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    popularAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                                }

                            }

                            public void onFinish() {
                            }
                        }.start();

                        AppActivity.popularHasNextPage = false;

                    }

                }
            }
        });


        return root;
    }
}
```

My adapter.java:

```
package org.vitaliy.moziapp.PopularFragment;

public class PopularAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PopularViewHolder> {


    static public String current_id;
    static public String current_category;


    ArrayList<String> movies_posters;
    ArrayList<String> movies_title;
    ArrayList<String> movies_id;
    ArrayList<String> movies_categories;
    ArrayList<String> movies_votes_pos;
    ArrayList<String> movies_votes_neg;
    ArrayList<String> movies_last_episode;


    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;


    public PopularAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> movies_posters,
                          ArrayList<String> movies_title,
                          ArrayList<String> movies_id,
                          ArrayList<String> movies_categories,
                          ArrayList<String> movies_votes_pos,
                          ArrayList<String> movies_votes_neg,
                          ArrayList<String> movies_last_episode){

        this.movies_posters = movies_posters;
        this.movies_title = movies_title;
        this.movies_id = movies_id;
        this.movies_categories = movies_categories;
        this.movies_votes_pos = movies_votes_pos;
        this.movies_votes_neg = movies_votes_neg;
        this.movies_last_episode = movies_last_episode;

        this.context = context;
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public PopularViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_movie, parent, false);
        return new PopularViewHolder(view);

    }

    @SuppressLint({"SetTextI18n", "NotifyDataSetChanged"})
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PopularViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        

        if(movies_categories.get(position).equals("s7")||
                movies_categories.get(position).equals("s93")) {

            holder.movie_last_episode.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            holder.movie_last_episode.setText(movies_last_episode.get(position));

        } else {
            holder.movie_last_episode.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }



        Picasso.with(context).load(movies_posters.get(position))
                .into(holder.movie_poster, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        holder.movie_icon.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }
                });

        holder.movie_title.setText(Html.fromHtml(movies_title.get(position)));

        holder.movie_btn.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {

                holder.movie_title.setSelected(b);

            }
        });

        holder.movie_votes_pos.setText(movies_votes_pos.get(position));
        holder.movie_votes_neg.setText(movies_votes_neg.get(position));



        holder.movie_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                current_id = movies_id.get(position);
                current_category = movies_categories.get(position);

                AppActivity.current_id = current_id;

                MovieVideosFragment.category = current_category;
                VideosAdapter.category = current_category;


                if (current_category.equals("s7") || current_category.equals("s93"))
                    AppActivity.loadSeriesAudio(current_id);
                else
                    AppActivity.loadMoviesAudio(current_id);

                AppActivity.isMoviesLoaded = false;
                AppActivity.isSeriesLoaded = false;

                MovieFragment.year = null;
                MovieFragment.actors = null;
                MovieFragment.genres = null;
                MovieFragment.countries = null;
                MovieFragment.short_story = null;


                AppActivity.loadMovieDescription(current_id);
                AppActivity.loadSimilar(current_id);


                MovieFragment.poster = movies_posters.get(position);
                MovieFragment.title = movies_title.get(position);

                context.startActivity(new Intent(context, MovieTab.class));


            }
        });


    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return movies_posters.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android TV RecyclerView focus interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247993/android-tv-recyclerview-focus-interaction)

Answer (score 0):

Apply this in your focus Listener

```
if(hasFocus){
   if(position == movies_posters.size-1){
    holder.item.nextFocusRight = R.id.item
  }

}
```

in the above code item is the recycler view id