# Focus switching to next row in nested recyclerview in FireTv App

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, amazon-fire-tv, nestedrecyclerview

In our fire tv app, we are using a nested recyclerview where every vertical item have a horizontal row as a child item like [playstore design](https://play.google.com/store).

Scrolling with dpad working fine normally but when i hold the right key for few seconds, item start scrolling very fast because it gets many events & within few second focus goes to the next random row  even current row has items to scroll. So this whole problem happening in horizontal scroll(child recyclerview). I have already tried many solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34277425/recyclerview-items-lose-focus?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39247993/android-tv-recyclerview-focus-interaction?noredirect=1&lq=1), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31596801/recyclerview-focus-scrolling?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Also tried the custom layout manager, custom focus layout & other approach like slowing down the recyclerview scroll etc approach but all not working.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this happens at the moment when the last item is in focus, and the next item is not visible, that is, the ViewHolder has not updated the data of the first cell, so it is not clear which element to show next as if the list has ended.

You need to make sure that at least the edge of the next element is always visible on the screen.

Maybe you should play with the cell size or divider.

Edit:
The secret is to use the leanback library. It isn't lost focus!

1. Your gradle:
   // Leanback support

   def leanback_version = "1.2.0-alpha01"
   implementation("androidx.leanback:leanback:$leanback_version")
2. Change in the layout from RecyclerView to HorizontalGridView (VerticalGridView)
3. Change in the Fragment import from RecyclerView.widget.GridLayoutManager to androidx.leanback.widget.GridLayoutManager
   It works very fast for me and the focus no longer jumps.

[Here](https://www.programmersought.com/article/61987325719/) a good article with animations but little outdated

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try this approach & will let you know.

Comment: Sorry for delay replying, I tried your suggestion but problem is still same!

Comment: Now I am just doing such a task for myself, I will try to do it now and then tell you

Comment: I have to use RecyclerView for vertical & horizontal both lists, this is my project requirement, But I will look at your suggestion also. Thanks

Comment: This views using the same RecyclerView adapters, but it require API level >=17.