# RecyclerView onFocus event

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, onfocus

I am using a `RecyclerView` with a `LinearLayoutManager` to populate an `ArrayList` of objects. What I need is how to implement the `onFocus` event when I change the focus from item to item? `onClick` event works fine, but the `onFocus` event has no effect.

**XML:**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/listchannels"
    android:layout_width="600dp"
    android:layout_height="560dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/channelList"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

My coding implementation of `onFocus` within the `ViewHolder` class in the `ListAdapter`:

```
@Override
public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
    int position = getAdapterPosition();

    if(hasFocus) {
        Toast.makeText(this.ctx, "Position : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

The `onFocus` event here has no effect, it doesn't work. Is it possible to implement the `onFocus` event on a `RecyclerView`?

Answer (score 0):

Check if this helps. I found somewhat similar to your issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/33190656/2779404

If not, let me try providing another approaches.

Comment: What exactly should i do? Should i add the code from GridLayoutManager in order the onFocus to function properly?